# Javascript variable into Jinga expression doesn't get replaced

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a Javascript function that inserts some HTML code into the HTML page of my Flask application when a button is clicked. Here is the Javascript function :

```
function add_html(n){
    var snippet = "<table> \
        <thead> \
        <tr> \
            <th scope=\"col\"></th> \
            '{% for keys in data[n]['returns'] %}<th scope=\"col\">{{keys}}</th>{% endfor %}' \
        </tr> \
        </thead>";

    $(snippet).insertAfter("#div-id");
}
```

I want the javascript variable `n` to be replaced by its value (it's an integer) but it doesn't work...
If I manually replaced it with an integer like `1` it works.
I have tried to replace `n` by `" + n + "` or `' + n + '` but nothing works. Any idea would be appreciated !

Comment: There is no way this can possibly work. Jinja is rendered on the server.

Comment: You can certainly have on-page javascript rendered dynamically by Jinja (or another template engine) - but what you can't do is use `n` here, which is a JS function parameter, in the template code, because that isn't known at the point the html (including this JS snippet) is rendered on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't get changed, you're passing n as a string literal.
You would probably want something like :

var snippet = ... {% for keys in data[' + n + ']['returns'] %} ...

Comment: It probably doesn't work because you have not alternated the string delimiters   (', ") properly. There is aprox. 3 double quotes inside another double quote in your code, and javascript can get confused if you use so many variations. Try cleaning the string a bit and see if it works. I've had lots of problems in the past with javascript messing with the delimiters

Comment: In my code, the double quotes `"` is used to contain the entire string, the `\"` indicates that I want a real double quote inside the string and the single quote `'` is for the Jinga expression. What else should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution that worked for me is to store the content of the variable sent from the render_template in python into a Javascript variable and use it on demand after without any Jinja expression.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stored_data = {{data|safe}};

    function add_html_tab(n){
        var keys_columns_html = "";

        for(keys in stored_data[n-1]["returns"]){
            console.log(keys);
            keys_columns_html += "<th scope=\"col\">" + keys + "</th>";
        }

        $(keys_columns_html).insertAfter("#myID");
    }

</script>
```